# Install SSH Certificate in WHM via SSH

Tags: ssl, ssh, installation, cpanel, whm

I have a server with around 300 cpanel accounts on WHM and would like to install SSL Certificates for those website in bulk (the certificates are all available already).

I know there is the WHM option to install SSL Certificates for Domains - however is there a way to do this via SSH as well?

WHM has multiple scripts like backing up Cpanel accounts, or restoring them, suspending them etc. Is there a way to install certificates like this too? (If so, I was not able to find it on the WHM documentation)

Or would I have to go the Apache / Centos installation way on SSH?

Thanks for any input or suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the WHM API 1 functions located in whmapi1 it is possible to achieve most of the WHM functions of the backend